# Angular DragAndDrop Cannot read property 'children' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality in an application and I found a great example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuiviw)

However; When I download the example and run in from my machiene, I get some weird behaviour. First of all it will only drop the item at the end of the list and secondly if I hover the "drop spot" with the item, I get the following error: [image]

Can someone please help me here, because this example solves om problems if i can get this error fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples

Comment: Hi. Thank you, Im familiar with this page. However, it doesn't have an example for multi-row lists and that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you please check if you've all the dependencies fulfilled? Especially `@angular/cdk`.

Comment: Yes, they are all there.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution in the attached blog which contains an example of drag-drop functionality implemented in the angular material table.

[Drag-Drop Angular Material Table](https://andorlogicfilter.blogspot.com/2022/07/material-dragdrop-table-in-this-post-we.html)